# Merpeople with ink-spraying heads?

Tags: mythical-creatures, merfolk

My merpeople have ink sacs in their heads, as they can spray ink from tentacles (like Medusa's snakes) on their head. The problem is, I don't know where said ink sac for each tentacle would go without the brain getting in the way.

Where in their head does the ink sac go so that it doesn't interfere with the brain and so that the brain doesn't interfere with it? I want them to look fairly human, so they can't stick out somewhere outside the head.

Comment: You are literally describing it in the first sentence of your question

Comment: Here, I'll add more details...

Comment: you just ambiguated the question

Comment: How did I ambiguate the question?

Comment: Greetings!  Looks like you're struggling a bit trying to ask your question.  If you haven't yet, do take a look at the [tour] and the [help] and learn [what Worldbuilding is all about](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7859/what-is-the-worldbuilding-site-about).  As it stands, you ask and answer your own question, which doesn't really make a lot of sense to us out here!  I think some of your earlier edits may actually be better forms of the query than the current. Could you edit again and really try to describe as best you can what your merpeople look like?

Comment: You ambiguated it by making it more confusing! In other words, we're confused by what it is you actually want to ask about, since you pretty much answered your own question. If you wish to *disambiguate*, then I'd say just give us some information as to what these people look like (head structure, body form, etc.) and offer some criteria for answering the question, like "I don't want the sac sticking off the top of their heads" or "they should look fairly human" or "they can look like a slimy octopus head!"

Comment: Thanks for improving your question! Much better now.

Answer (score 1):

### Inside the tentacles!

I know what your thinking "but isn't that sticking out of the head?" and yes, it technically is but I'll explain.

You have tentacles, quite a few. So you can take the ink sac and give each tentacle a mini ink sac, some animals already have more than one gland for producing substances to defend themselves, so it's not a completely outlandish idea.

Comment: Lol I'm an idiot for not thinking of that... ‍♀️

Answer (score 0):

The mermaids could have a rostral organ in their nose, which would allow for a single large ink-sac in the space that is occupied by the nasal cavities and sinuses in humans